# What is the correct Index column ordering based on a SQL Query?

Tags: oracle, indexing, query-optimization, database-indexes

Consider the generic query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE COL_1 IN ('item1', 'item2')
      AND COL_2 = 100
    ORDER BY COL_3
) subquery1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COL_A, MAX(COL_B) FROM TABLE_2
    GROUP BY COL_A
    HAVING COUNT(COL_B) > 2
) subquery2
ON subquery1.COL_1 = subquery2.COL_A
```

Assume that the query itself is optimized. If I wanted to create the an 'optimized' index around a query like this, what indexes should I be creating? In particular, which **order** are the indexes' columns be?

From my understanding, the first columns should be the columns used in the `WHERE` clause, then the `ORDER BY` clause, and lastly the `SELECT` clause. Is this true? What about the others, such as `GROUP BY`'s, `HAVING`'s, and `JOIN`'s - when should they be considered?

Also if necessary, assume that this is an Oracle database. (But I imagine column ordering would be the same for other platforms.)